# How to dipslay subcategories list on category page. Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way I can edit woocommmerce category page without any pugins?

I need to display child categories with photos, and just then below the categories I would like to display all products of the parent category.

Can this be done?

Maybe there is a function, code or something to achieve this? For example (what i want to achieve):

Page title 
Child categories (displayed with photos)

Using Wordpress + Woocommerce + Elementor + Shoptimizer theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You just need to use this function:

```
    function woocommerce_product_category( $args = array() ) {
    $woocommerce_category_id = get_queried_object_id();
  $args = array(
      'parent' => $woocommerce_category_id
  );
  $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
  if ( $terms ) {
      echo '<ul class="woocommerce-categories">';
      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
          echo '<a href="' .  esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '"><li class="woocommerce-product-category-page">';
            woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail( $term );
          echo '<h2>';
          echo '<a href="' .  esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">';
          echo $term->name;
          echo '</a>';
          echo '</h2>';
          echo '</li></a>';
      }
      echo '</ul>';
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_product_category', 100 );
```

I hope it helped someone. Thanks